# bash script for removing a line of text from a txt file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Trying to do a delete script after a certain criteria is met. Tried using sed command and input it into if else to compare to string (user input using read command) to compare if they are inside the txt file.

My commands are as follows:

```
read -p "Book Title to delete: " bookT
read -p "Book Author to delete: " Author

#grep "$bookT" file.txt >> tempvar1
#grep "$Author" file.txt >> tempvar2

if grep -q "$bookT" file.txt && grep -q "$Author" file.txt
then
sed -i -e "s/$bookT/$author/d" file.txt
echo "Book deleted successfully!"
else
echo "book not deleted!"
fi
```

Comment: you want `tempvar1=$(grep "$book1" file.txt)` etc . But all this code can be simplified significantly. `if grep -q "$book1" file.txt && grep -q "$author" ; then sed ...; fi`. And there are other ways to reduce further the processing. Good luck.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Also use double quotes:  tmpvar1="$(grep ...)" aso spaces, etc., are not parsed by the shell.

Comment: Hi, when i run the script, the sed command part returns,sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'. i have edited as shown above.

Comment: @StephenOng Your `sed` expression is wrong. You don't want to substitute anything, you want to find the line with 'bookT' and 'Author' and delete them, e.g. `sed -i "/$bookT/d"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hi when i remove -e and  s, i received this error: sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown command: `o'

Comment: I don't know of an `'o'` command -- so `sed` is right... To remove the line with book, your `sed` command will look like `sed "/$bookT/d"` ***note:*** the use of *double-quotes* to allow variable expansion to take place, not single-quotes you use without variables...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin didn't use any command with o inside... this is the sed line that i have edited with that error.     sed -i "/$BookT/$Author/d" file.txt

Comment: Can you show us what is in `file1.txt` showing a book and author you want to delete? Your approach above may fail if the same author writes more than one book. Currently we have to guess at the what the lines you are working with are.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin hi i had figured out what is the issue. i should have put it as "/$booKT:$author/d" file.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are conceptual problems and a syntax problem here.

From your `sed` I expect the `file.txt` to contain something like:

```
Moby Dick/Herman Melville
Lolita/Vladimir Nabokov
The art of computer programming/Donald Knuth
```

In that case, the `sed` should be:

```
sed -i "/$bookT.*$author/d" BookDB.txt
```

or `\/` instead of `.*` or something like that.

One of the other problems is that `file.txt` changes into `BookDB.txt`. You should look at that, because it seems strange to me.

Another conceptual problem is, that if I enter "Moby Dick" as book and "Nabokov" as author, both greps will succeed, and you will try to delete a non-existing book.

Comment: Hi yup have input it wrongly. Anyway i figured the issue out. Thanks!